# Eigen Library: why is my function copying my argument when it shouldn't?

Tags: c++, templates, eigen

In my case, the MatrixXd object "AA" is a large matrix and absolutely cannot be copied. It seems that the below function should not copy it, but in fact it does copy it. I'm by no means a programming and surely I'm doing something horribly wrong, but I cannot figure out just what it is

```
void GKLBidiag(const Ref<const MatrixXd>& AA, double& eigenv, Ref<VectorXd> v,     Ref<VectorXd> alpha, Ref<VectorXd> beta) {

  VectorXd u(AA.rows());
  VectorXd Uprev(v.size());
  VectorXd Vnew(v.size());
  const int kmax(alpha.size());
  MatrixXd B(MatrixXd::Zero(kmax, kmax));


  v.normalize();

  for (int i = 0; i < kmax; i++) {
    Uprev = u;
    u = AA * v;
    if (i > 0) {
      u -= beta(i - 1) * Uprev;
      //add reorthogonalization
    }
    alpha(i) = u.norm();
    u /= alpha(i);
    Vnew = AA.adjoint() * u - alpha(i) * v;
    beta(i) = Vnew.norm();
    v = Vnew.array() / beta(i);
  }

  B.diagonal() = alpha;
  for (int i = 0; i < kmax - 1; i++) {
    B(i, i + 1) = beta(i);
  }

  JacobiSVD<MatrixXd> svd(B);
  eigenv = pow(svd.singularValues()(0), 2);

}
```

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How do you know it is being copied?

Comment: I ran the function when AA was an object of 2gigabytes. When the function is called (even before the loop is run; I know because I printed a statement and had it pause for a bit), then the used up memory doubles immediately

Comment: Add your own copy and assignment constructors to the class and see where it is getting called. Just write cout if you don't want to implement them - for now you just want to find the culprit

Comment: Maybe it's this line? `VectorXd u(AA.rows());`

Comment: Brian, I made a change and just passed what that value would be and that does not appear to be the offending line

Comment: AbhiP, I'm not entirely sure what you mean

Comment: Just because the memory use has doubled does not mean AA was copied. If you create a copy constructor and put a breakpoint in it, you will see if it is being copied or not. The Microsoft heap manager estimates how much memory to assign to the process heap from the system heap from the size of previous memory allocations, and scaling by a factor.

Comment: Why, then, would memory use double as soon as this function is called?

Comment: Is `AA` really a MatrixXd object? Or might it be a row-major Matrix? or maybe you are calling `GKLBidiag` with AA.transpose() or something like that? Also, what if you declare `GKLBidiag` with a standard reference: `GKLBidiag(const MatrixXd& AA,...)`. The Ref<> class is to allow some flexibility to accept not only a MatrixXd but also a Map or a Block object without copy.

Comment: I tried your suggestion before moving the the Ref<> class. It's definitely not row-major. I'm not calling it with the transpose either

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the extra memory is required when you compute the adjoint matrix `AA.adjoint()` on the fly, with the same size as `AA`.